# completely unregulated drugs and their effect on economy

Tags: economy, medicine

In this world when your 16 years old skater daughter buys a monster energy, it doesn't just contain proteins and caffeine but might have things such as Anavar, Trenbolone, cocaine and even Period Suppressing Drugs for that true **MONSTER** energy.

Now the vitamin tablets that ''allegedly'' give you a boost in energy as they say in TV commercials actually really give a boost in energy due to all the drugs inside.

Could this complete freedom for drug distribution boost the economy of a country when compared to regulated countries?

Comment: Throughout the overwhelming large part of history no state had any laws regulating what drugs a free person could sell, could buy, and could ingest. You are describing the world before WW1, and in a large part also before WW2. The idea that the State can regulate what a person chooses to drink or eat is *extremely* modern, and, as far as I can see, it is already approaching the end of its short life. The world did just fine, thank you, before well-meaning politicians decided that it was their business to decide what person was allowed to smoke.

Comment: @AlexP actually didn't know that, they almost make it feel like some restrictions where always present, good to know.

Comment: Why do you think that Coca-Cola is called Coca-Cola? it still contains [cola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kola_nut) nuts extract... but it is no longer allowed to include the first part of its name. (Fun factoid: in 1839 the British went to war against China because the Chinese had the audacity to forbid the importation and consumption of opium. The British won.)

Comment: *"completely unregulated drugs"* Completely? are you sure about that? [it's all fun & games until someone's jaw falls off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eben_Byers) // on the upside of course the hastened (planned?) obsolescence of all those production units (aka people) you can expect should help ameliorate things like unemployment // which could be good for the economy in some ways :)

Comment: @AlexP *"in 1839 the British went to war against China because the Chinese had the audacity to forbid the importation and consumption of opium"* // Slander!! that wasn't it at all, we went to war because they had the audacity to forbid ***us*** from selling ***them*** opium :)

Comment: How cheap are these monster energy drinks?

Comment: @Pelinore Don't forget that the reason the East India Company was importing opium was because England was addicted to the tea that China was selling for silver only and bankrupting England. Opium was seen as a way to get hard currency back from China. The lesson we can learn is that importing cocaine to China might be a way to change the balance of payments issue we have.

Comment: @DavidR Ah yes, we were only returning the favour, they gave us that awful debilitating drug of choice (tea) so we gave them opium :) the financial profit from selling them opium were of course a strong driver in our decision making process, pretty sure most of the profits from both sides of the trade ended up with the British companies involved mind, more a case those companies wanted to profit from both legs of the journey, they were the ones driving the decisions after all, I doubt they cared about the UKs trade balance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Oregon](https://www.usnews.com/news/best-states/articles/2020-12-10/oregon-just-decriminalized-all-drugs-heres-why-voters-passed-this-groundbreaking-reform) and [Portugal](https://time.com/longform/portugal-drug-use-decriminalization/#:%7E:text=But%20in%202001%2C%20Portugal%20took,here%2C%20January%2012%2C%202017.) have decriminalized all drugs.  You'll see drug tourism money if you have an open border.**

Demand for drugs is [inelastic](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2006/01/060112034638.htm), so making it legal probably won't change actual consumption that much.  It will draw people already buying the drugs in the black market to spend money legally in your state or country.

It will boost your economy by taking drug money out of other places.  If your borders are pretty open, then yes, you'll see an economic boom.  You've essentially realized all the black market drug dealer money.

**EDIT: Demand for Illegal drugs is inelastic**

Demand for [recreational drugs](https://serc.carleton.edu/econ/tbl-econ/activities/191385.html) is [inelastic](https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w10976/w10976.pdf) as well.  Which makes sense.  If you're addicted to heroin, you'll pay any price to alleviate withdrawal.  Many people refuse to take drugs even if it's offered free, like in the anti-drug videos.

Even with legal or partially legal drugs like alcohol and cannabis, price is still relatively inelastic.  People will pay $10+ for a beer at a sporting event or concert.  Most new distilleries and breweries don't compete on price but on quality.  [Demand for alcohol is also inelastic.](https://www.euromonitor.com/article/price-elasticities-in-alcoholic-drinks)

Most cannabis dispensaries have gone mainly to extract-based products, which are more expensive.  Using extracts customers can buy only what they want, such as CBD.  They can also choose the strain they want.

Comment: "Oregon and Portugal have already done this" - no, they have not. "Decriminalized" does not mean "unregulated". Many drugs in Oregon and Portugal are still illegal, but carry civil instead of criminal penalties. Neither enjoy free, unregulated distribution or consumption of prescription or recreational drugs. These examples are a step in the right direction, but nowhere near the scenario the OP describes.

Comment: *"Demand for drugs is inelastic, so making it legal probably won't change actual consumption"* not entirely sure about that, are you only considering medication for illness? if so then that would be largely right yes, but if you're including recreational drugs it wouldn't be I think.

Comment: Part of the reason for marijuana extract products is that many people want to use them for health benefits - e.g. CBD oil for arthritis pain relief - without the psychoactive effects.

Comment: @Pelinore - added more information for inelastic demand for drugs drugs, including illegal drugs.  It's fairly well documented in in economic literature.

Comment: *"makes sense. If you're addicted to heroin"* No, I'm afraid I'd have to say it doesn't make sense, sorry :) there are an awful *lot* of *'relatively'* un-additive illegal recreational drugs out there // & demand for those can be very elastic indeed when subjected to factors like price & legality.

Comment: @Pelinore - added more links.  Alcohol is also inelastic, and is legal in many countries.

Comment: I've not studied your alcohol link closely but from a brief glance it doesn't appear to support your claim, only shows retail sales & excludes pub sales (from your link: *'Note: Retail sales only (excludes on-trade)'*) // retail price is cheaper than pub price so retail market share (& to start with total retail sales) are expected to increase as price does while overall sales drop (people switch to the cheaper option initially) // & also from personal experience (of my own buying habits) I can't agree with your conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

### Lesser drugs will be profitable.

Selling weed, LCD, ecstasy, or other drugs which are not much worse than alcohol or are safer will sell for lots of money and boost the economy.

### Heavy drugs will have a net negative effect.

[As the opoid crisis proved, having a highly addictive and euphoric drug widely available has a massive cost in health, money, and lives.](https://www.drugabuse.gov/drug-topics/opioids/opioid-overdose-crisis)

> In 2019, nearly 50,000 people in the United States died from opioid-involved overdoses.1 The misuse of and addiction to opioids—including prescription pain relievers, heroin, and synthetic opioids such as fentanyl—is a serious national crisis that affects public health as well as social and economic welfare. The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention estimates that the total "economic burden" of prescription opioid misuse alone in the United States is $78.5 billion a year, including the costs of healthcare, lost productivity, addiction treatment, and criminal justice involvement.2

Comment: if everyone is both buying the drugs to poison themselves and also buying the cure, doesn't that actually help the economy because the make more money circulate? and if everyone dies younger, doesn't that mean that the average population will stop being old? which mens less pensions, which means less people that get money without actually producing?

Comment: When people die, or are disabled, or are injured they become less able to produce money via jobs and education and such.

A lot will turn to crime to fund their drug habits as well, which means mugging or killing more productive civilians. Doesn't matter if there's more stuff to be sold if people don't have jobs.

Comment: The opioid crisis in the USA is a bad example, though. It was engineered and does not represent the normal drug consumption and drug addiction dynamic.

Comment: If drugs are completely unregulated it's not gonna be hard for other people to engineer people taking lots of drugs. It's an example of what happens when a hard drug is super free for people to take, and pushed by the government and businesses.

Comment: @Otkin *"was engineered and does not represent the normal drug consumption"* You're suggesting many of the negative impacts were caused by it 'being' illegal'? or something else?

Comment: You're overlooking the strong possibility that this was and is a manufactured "crisis".  Basically more propaganda from the Drug Warriors, whose continued job prospects are threatened by the progress of marijuana legalization.

Comment: @jamesqf "manufactured" meaning that it does not really exist?

Comment: @Pelinore No, negative impacts are real and they are associated with the nature of addiction, not the legality of drugs. What I was referring to is that the patterns of addiction present in the USA are different from the patterns and dynamics of opioid addiction elsewhere. According to 2019 CDC data, 73% of opioid OD deaths occur among ages 25-54. Normally, though, people of these ages are a low-risk group when it comes to substance use disorders. Moreover, addiction in most cases starts with prescription drugs. While the prevalence of conditions that require pain medications in the USA[cont.]

Comment: [...] is the same as in Europe, opioids are prescribed 4 times (IIRC) more often and for a longer time. Additionally, patients are misinformed about the addictive properties of prescribed drugs and doctors are paid to promote and prescribe those drugs. Among other things, this leads to the high prevalence of opioid addiction among adult women in a relatively good socio-economic situation (normally one of the lowest risk groups for drug addiction). Today, OD cases for women in the USA grow faster than for men. Again, this is not normal.

Comment: @Alexander: Meaning that the underlying situation - lack or underuse of better ways of treating chronic pain, for instance - has been spun into an artificial crisis, for political reasons.  Which in turn means that people who use these drugs to manage pain can't readily get them legally, so turn to illegal sources.  Those have poor quality & dosage control, so the risk of accidental overdose increases.

Comment: @jamesqf - if you think this was all done for political reasons, then the scope of this discussion is going to exceed Worldbuilding SE domain.

Comment: @Alexander: Why? Aren't political decisions part of Worldbuilding? Especially when the question seems to be a what-if starting from the current real world.  We do have that history, especially in the US, of going from pretty much unregulated drugs pre-20th century, to various episodes of politically-motivated illegality: Prohibition, "Reefer Madness", the "War on Drugs" - all primarily political.

Comment: @jamesqf politically motivated regulations is one thing, but blaming mass addition on politically motivated conspiracy is quite the other.

Comment: @Alexander: You misunderstand me, I think.  Fairly large-scale use of opiods (or alcohol, cannabis, video game, &c) is just an event.  The politically-motivated conspiracy is in turning the event into a "crisis", so as to get more law enforcement powers and tax money.  The US DEA alone has a budget of $3 billion a year, and employs around 10,000 people (per Google).  The BATF and various state agencies add even more.  Most of them would be unemployed if not for the various manufactured "crises".

Answer (score 2):

**Overall economic effect will be negative**

There are two aspects of this question:

1. Is recreational drug use (in itself) positive or negative for the economy?
2. Would deregulation of narcotics increase or decrease their overall use?

For #1, the answer is "negative". In US, in 2017 alone, and only for opioids, economic cost is estimated at [$1,021 billion (just above 1 trillion)](https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/volumes/70/wr/mm7015a1.htm) US dollars. To me, this figure is so staggering that I won't even try to tally up the upside of the drug trade.

For #2, the answer is less clear cut, but in my opinion it would be "increase". Case study: tobacco use. Tobacco (a recreational drug) enjoyed increasing success for the most part of 20th century, which was fueled by massive advertisement by the tobacco companies. When significant restrictions were placed on smoking, as well as advertisement, tobacco use plummeted.

Comment: That report estimates that each case of "fatal opioid overdose" cost eleven and a half million dollars. I knew that funerals were expensive in the USA, but I didn't know that they were quite so expensive. What on earth did they do for each "fatal opioid overdose" to justify eleven and a half million dollars?

Comment: @AlexP I presume this includes things like "lost wages" - i.e. the deceased would have kept contributing to the economy as a whole.

Comment: @Alexander *"I presume this includes things like "lost wages""* was '[opportunity cost'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost) the term you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of freedom provides opportunities. It also takes away opportunities.

In this environment the product only has to look good enough to sell and be cheap to produce. That can encourage a race for the bottom. Many will compete to get to the bottom first.

Others, who have a quality product, will innovate to get that quality recognized for what it is. This is why brands exist. But without any regulation you can't register trademarks. So all you can do is infuse your brand with anti-counterfeiting protections that let normal people detect a counterfeit.

Hinez basically did this when they started selling Ketchup in a clear glass bottle so you could see the product before you bought it. To this day some products are given out as free samples so you can taste for yourself.

But drugs are hard to identify by sight if diluted in a drink. So if you really don't trust whoever is selling the energy drink you may prefer to buy the drugs separately and mix them yourself.

Comment: Trademark protection and drug regulation are two very separate parts of the law, and one is much older than the other. There is no (or very very little) regulation of trademarks; anybody can register any trademark they please, as long as it doesn't clash with an already registered mark. (In many countries you don't even have to register your trademark; all you have to do is use it in commerce, and the law will protect your mark. For example, Stella Artois beer has used the Stella Artois name since the 14th century.)

Comment: @AlexP well yeah, that's the point. If I have a unique trademark I can build it's reputation with a quality product and keep others from making low quality counterfeits that get confused with my product. That only works if regulations exist.

Comment: I think you are confused about the meaning of the the word "regulation". It is not a synonym for "law". As I said, there is very little regulation of trademarks, essentially forbidding the use of obscene words and symbols. Other than that, you are free to use whatever words and symbols you want.

Comment: @AlexP I think you are confused about the meaning of "completely".

Comment: Or you go to your local pharmacist who mixes up the drink at the soda fountain - which is exactly how many soda recipes actually started. See the history of Dr. Pepper as an example.

Comment: @candied_orange let me repeat what Alex said, because I don't think you got it, trademark law is not drug regulation, it can, has & will exist irrespective of the existence or not of drug regulations, it has nothing to do with the question as written & nothing to do with any answer to the question as written.

Comment: @Pelinore let me repeat what Red said, because I don't think you got it: "Completely unregulated drugs".

Comment: Unregulated drugs only means you can sell anything you want not that you can use anyone else's 'name' (essentially what a trademark is for a company & its products) while doing it // these are two completely separate areas of law & regulation & trademark is not included in the OPs question, so I repeat, you just haven't understood what Alex said, or the question as OP wrote it (regardless of what he maybe meant).

Comment: @Pelinore [you're my hero](https://xkcd.com/386/)

Comment: @DavidR this is something that we actually study in History of Pharmacy LOL Coca-cola, Pepsi, Dr. Pepper, 7-Up (it used to contain lithium), Angostura bitters, Tonic water (of Gin & Tonic fame), and multiple local beverages... and there are also the ingredients that got subjected to control with time such as heroin (created to be a "more palatable" replacement for morphine in *cough syrup*)

Answer (score 1):

Without *any* regulation is bad, straight out detrimental to the free market. There needs to be regulation enough to allow consumers to be certain of content.

That is if a person buys a pill of 2mg narcotic A plus binder, that is what it should be. It should not be vitamin C or just binder or drug B narcotic D etc.

Things that bring it closer to a free market will make the market more efficient.  Which will improve some people's quality of life by making it easier to access desired entertainments. In this regard the economy will be better.

However drugs are not infrastructure, they by themselves do not increase production. So I would not expect big change in the economy beyond reducing costs of enforcement.

If people consume recreational drugs in very large quantities I would expect a negative impact on the economy as everybody is tripping and not working.

#### Conclusion

If USA switches all current recreational drugs to the status of 'over the counter' drugs. I would expect a boost in terms of decreased costs to enforcement and jail/prison costs. A longer term boost of less broken families.

Answer (score 0):

### It's about the right to bear arms ... and the failures of capitalism.

Your country may well regard itself as pursuing a "Second Amendment", since it is protecting the right of its citizens to possess dangerous things.  And it may well *need* to, since some of these drugs are indeed potent weapons.  A derivative of fentanyl, for example, was used to save the lives of the majority of the hostages in the [2002 Moscow theater hostage crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_theater_hostage_crisis) by incapacitating their attackers; but even with the best of intentions, in that event it also proved capable of mass fatalities.

The effect on the economy can be hard to quantify, but note that deregulation can be used as a means of *restraining* trade in a sector.  For example, in the U.S. dietary supplements were spared from prohibition under [DSHEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dietary_Supplement_Health_and_Education_Act_of_1994), but as an alternative, regulation was made so weak that the supplements are often sold without the described ingredient from the label or may even contain undeclared prescription drugs.  This deterred a great deal of very interesting community-based science development that might otherwise have been done to develop products like *Oxalobacter* or *Nymphaea*.

It makes sense that allowing commerce will be more merciful and better for the economy than banning it, but you'll need to look deep into the details and the underlying philosophy to produce an effective theory of just *how* to do that fairly, or how to operate any truly fair marketplace in any society.  To shape such visions is the highest calling of the sci-fi author, and at times it is even recognized as such by critics - I wish you good luck!